# text larger columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I recently used to bootstrap a project, but I can not understand why I have this problem.

[image]

As you can see from the screen, I set a div to 4 columns, but the text comes out. 
You will probably also happened to any of you .. anyone knows the solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your code, idelly in a jsfiddle. Looks initially like an overflow or wrapping problem.

Answer (score 2):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQKcy/7/)

It's because the text is overflowing the container, and not breaking, add:

`overflow:hidden;` to prevent this overflow from being visible, or `word-wrap:break-word;` to break the text and wrap it back within the boundaries of the container. Have a look at the fiddle posted above to see the differences between these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide over flow just use

```
overflow:hidden;
```

And if you want to show it using scroll bar just use

```
overflow:scroll;
```